# Is there an issue when using record type with defaultable values as input for a GraphQL resource in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

My GraphQL service written in Ballerina 2201.1.1 (Swan Lake Update 1) looks something like below.

```
resource function get personalClaims(types:ClaimFilter filter, int 'limit = 100, int offset = 0) 
        returns types:PersonalClaim[]|error {
```

And the types:ClaimFilter record is as follows.

```
public type ClaimFilter record {
    string[] ids = [];
    string? email = ();
};
```

My issue is if I do not send a value for `ids` in the `filter`, `ids` will not be defaulted to `[]`. Instead it gives the error
`"Field \"filter.ids\" of required type \"[String!]!\" was not provided."`

This seems like it is a bug or some sort of limitation. Is it? or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Seems like this is a bug. Created an issue to track this: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-standard-library/issues/3646

Comment: Noted with thanks @ThisaruG

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug that is already fixed. The question is not likely to be useful for anyone in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in the Ballerina GraphQL package. It is now fixed with the GraphQL 1.3.5 version, which is released in Ballerina central.